# How Realm handles dynamic dispatch with List<T> and RealmOptional<T>?

Tags: swift, realm

Realm relies on dynamic dispatch to access ObjectiveC runtime for some KVC mechanisms. Model properties should be marked with `dynamic` keyword to enable KVC that is used by `Realm` objects to fill them with exact values. So you can have model defined like this:

```
class Car: Object {
    dynamic var color = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}
```

At some level you would be able to set properties like this:

```
var car = Car()
car["color"] = "white"
car["age"] = 20
```

This works for all basic types like `Int` or `String` but doesn't work with generic classes and structures since they can't be represented in Objective C. Realm uses two of those types:

1. [`List<T>`](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift/List.swift)
2. [`RealmOptional<T>`](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift/Optional.swift)

When adding properties of these types to the Realm models, you add them without dynamic keyword:

```
let cars = List<Car>
let registration = RealmOptional<String>
```

What mechanism Realm uses to set and read data of those types without using dynamic dispatch?

**Update 1**

Upon some inspection, I've found that Realm uses some Objective C runtime methods like `class_copyPropertyList()` and `property_getName()` for introspection of property names. What I haven't found yet is how properties are populated with correct data when you read from Realm? Is that part of the `ObjectStore` C++ framework?

Comment: It's all open source. Probably a good place to start looking is the implementation of `subscript` in `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic properties such like `List<T>` or `RealmOptional<T>` cannot be appeared from Objective-C. Realm uses Swift's reflection (`Mirror()`) to inspect those.

(See https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/b71daecd0f4cf7a89fcb30178be02f506d9b3124/RealmSwift/Object.swift#L310-L316)

Then directly access their `ivar`: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/76d1018b32ba98babce31afbefd31863075cde8c/Realm/RLMObjectSchema.mm#L217-L223

These generic properties are dispatched statically. Realm cannot hook accessing those. That's why those properties must be declared as `let`. Realm cannot see re-assign the properties.